# Running Time Calculation

Tags: time-complexity, complexity-theory, code-complexity

I am trying to learn time complexities. I have come across a problem that is confusing me. I need help to understand this:

my_func takes an array input of size n. It runs three for loops. In the third loop it calls for another function that is O(1) time.

```
def my_func(A): 
  for (int i=1; i<n; i++)
    for (int j=1; j<i; j++)
      for (int k=1; k<j; k++)
        some_other_func();
```

My Questions:

1. Am I right if I say that total number of steps performed by my_func() is O(n^3) because:

   1. the first for loop goes from 1 to n-1
   2. the second for loop goes from 1 to n-2
   3. the third loop goes from 1 to n-3
2. What is asymptotic run time and what is the asymptotic run time for the above algorithm?
3. What is the meaning of the following:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> Am I right if I say that total number of steps performed by my_func()
> is O(n^3)

Yes, its time-complexity is `O(n^3)`.

> What is asymptotic run time and what is the asymptotic run time for
> the above algorithm?

The limiting behavior of the execution time of an algorithm when the size of the problem goes to infinity [[here]](https://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/HTML/asymptoticTimeComplexity.html#:%7E:text=Definition%3A%20The%20limiting%20behavior%20of,the%20problem%20goes%20to%20infinity.). for example:

```
lim (n^3) when n-> infinite
```

> What is the meaning of the following

1st, it shows dependant variables `k->j->i` as it is. Moreover, what if all of the variables(i, j, k) were independent of each other? for example a constant `x` then each loop would iterate for `x` times but here k depends on j, and j depends on I. for example:

```
x(x(x)) = sigma(sigma(sigma(O(1))))
```

2nd, time-complexity is investigated on large input. Therefore, either the variables are dependant or non-dependant, big O would be `O(n^3)`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's O(n^3), and that IS the asymptotic run time.  The sum expression at the end means the same thing as the three nested loops at the top, assuming "some_other_func()" is `sum = sum + 1`.